# $.getJSON not recognice JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to read a json from my Django server. I'm using `$.getJSON` call, but it fails. What's wrong?

**Here's my Ajax code:**

```
get: function() {
    $.getJSON("http://url.herokuapp.com/getdata?jsoncallback=?",
    {
        tags: "jquery,javascript",
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
    },
    function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(item){
        console.log(item);
        });
    });
}
```

**And this is the error:**

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
   {"string"*:* "Prove that I send JSON typing some random text", "status": "Done"}
```

What is marked with `* *`  is where the error is located.

**MORE INFO:**

I'm starting a Phonegap app that will work with my existing web app (Just in case this info it helps)

Comment: Your code seems incomplete or with errors. What is the scope?

Comment: Just ran `$.getJSON` code in firebug console. running fine except 404 for mentioned url .

Answer (score 2):

The URL you are requesting data from is returning JSON, but by adding `callback=?` to the URL you are telling jQuery to treat it as [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Either remove the `callback=?` from the URL so that you can process it as JSON (noting that you may have to implement CORS support on the server to grant cross domain permission) or change the server so it will emit JSONP instead of JSON.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to change server side so it emits JSONP, any tip on how to do it nicely in Django?